# Highcharts for Python doesn't render in Jupyter

Tags: python, highcharts

I am trying out highcharts-core for Python to display js based charts. [github.com/highcharts-for-python/highcharts-core](https://%20github.com/highcharts-for-python/highcharts-core)

Using the sample code from the docs:

```
from highcharts_core.chart import Chart
from highcharts_core.options.series.area import LineSeries
from highcharts_core.global_options.shared_options import SharedOptions

my_chart = Chart(container = 'target_div',
                 options = {
                     'series': [
                         LineSeries(data = [0, 5, 3, 5])
                     ]
                 },
                 variable_name = 'myChart')

# Now this will render the contents of "my_chart" in your Jupyter Notebook
my_chart.display()
```

I get the following "error" once the cell finishing running after about 3 seconds:

```
Something went wrong with the Highcharts.js script. It should have been automatically loaded, but it did not load for over 3 seconds. Check your internet connection, and then if the problem persists please reach out for support.
```

what might be going on here?

Comment: Network error at the time? Tried again later? I tried your code and it worked after I ran `%pip install highcharts-core` in my JupyterLab. Please always include a link for resources like this, such as , "I am trying to use highcharts-core from https://github.com/highcharts-for-python/highcharts-core." Searching 'highcharts' at PyPI brings up a lot of stuff that isn't this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chiming in as the author of the Highcharts for Python toolkit. I'm having some difficulty reproducing the issue you're seeing.

What version of Highcharts Core for Python are you using, and what version of Jupyter Notebook (or Jupyter Labs)?

Generally, that error message appears if the chart does not render in about 3 seconds. The most common reason for this is temporary network issues which delay the loading of the JavaScript modules that are needed for the chart to render. Those JavaScript modules get loaded asynchronously the first time you try to display a Highcharts visualization in your notebook. If that is - indeed - the cause, if you clear the output of that cell and re-run the cell it may render correctly for you (because by that point the scripts will have asynchronously been loaded successfully).

Hope this helps, and feel free to provide some more background if you're continuing to run into this issue - with more details like the versions of Jupyter you're using and the version of the Highcharts Core for Python library you're using, that can help diagnose the issue if it isn't just momentarily network latency.

ETA: Turns out the problem was resolved after upgrading to v.1.1.1 of the Highcharts for Python library, and *also* disabling and re-enabling some of the Jupyter Notebook-related VSCode extensions. It's unclear whether the sequence of disabling/re-enabling the VSCode extensions mattered for the resolution, or whether it was one specific extension causing a conflict, or whether it was a combination of the extensions. The extensions indicated for further research are: Jupyter, Jupyter Cell Tags, Jupyter Notebook Renderers, Jupyter Slide Show, Jupyter Keymap.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your comment.

I am using `highcharts-core=1.0.2` and the Jupyter as well as ipykernel versions are as below:

`IPython: 8.12.0`
`ipykernel: 6.22.0`
`ipywidgets: 8.0.6`
`jupyter_client: 8.2.0`
`jupyter_core: 5.3.0`
`jupyter_server: 2.5.0`
`jupyterlab: 3.6.3`

I am using WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) for development with dependencies managed by Poetry.

Unfortunately I have trouble rendering on every call to the code (not just the first call) and clearing cell output and re-running results in the same error.

Comment: Thanks, Bardia. Let me try to re-create that environment on my side and see if I can recreate the issue. I'll hopefully update my answer for you shortly.

Comment: Thanks Chris. It might be worthwhile to add that I am running the notebook within vscode with that environment.

Comment: Ah - thanks, Bardia. That is an important detail. Are you also running any VSCode extensions that interact with your Jupyter Notebook environment (e.g. the Jupyter extension, Jupyter PowerToys, VS Code Jupyter Notebook Previewer, etc.) ?

Comment: I checked and I have a bunch of Jupyter related vscode extensions running: Jupyter, Jupyter Cell Tags, Jupyter Notebook Renderers, Jupyter Slide Show, Jupyter Keymap

Comment: Thanks, Bardia. Those potentially may have an impact. I’ll try to recreate that environment in a Docker container and experiment to see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: So I still haven't gotten your environment exactly recreated in a Docker container (I'm hoping to get that sorted shortly), but in the meantime I did want to let you know that there's a new release for Highcharts for Python that went out today that patches a bug in our Jupyter rendering. That *might* help this issue - but it might not. Either way, I'll be working to reproduce your issue ASAP to help diagnose it.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have now managed to render the charts. Following your last comment, I upgraded the library version to v1.1.1. That by itself did not resolve the problem. I, then, experimentally, disabled and re-enabled all 5 Jupyter-related vscode extensions I mentioned above, at which point I was able to see the plot (without having to re-run the notebook). It's hard to say which one of these many factors was actually responsible for the fix, but maybe this is something helpful for you and your team. Thanks for your help debugging this, I'll report if there are any other problems down the road.

Comment: Hi Bardia - glad to hear that you were able to resolve the issue! And definitely thanks for helping me identify that there's something odd happening with VSCode extensions: We'll definitely look into it to see what might be conflicting and why. I'll update my StackOverflow answer to reflect what ultimately worked for you. And if you run into other issues, please just let us know: We're happy to help.

Comment: I am encountering a new rendering issue where my Jupyter environment would only render if .display() is called without passing on the SharedOptions. Passing the SharedOptions would result in no error, but a blank output. I have confirmed SharedOptions are configured correctly, and having them as part of the chart options (local not shared or global) and leaving display() parameter-less would work but I'd like to have a SharedOptions object rendered across all my charts.

Comment: Hi Bardia - thanks, can you email us a snippet of your Python code to support@highchartspython.com ? Specifically, the section of code when you’re instantiating your Chart instance and then the line when you’re calling .display() with the SharedOptions instance. Doing so should work and should render properly, but it’d be helpful to take a closer look to try and troubleshoot what might be happening.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove `nbclassic` from your URL: `http://localhost:8888/nbclassic/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb`

When you remove it, it becomes like this:
`http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb`

Now try and see if it is working. After I did this, it started working for me.