# Highcharts in Jupyter Notebook Throws Highcharts.js script error while trying to display the charts

Tags: javascript, windows, highcharts, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I'm trying to replicate one of the highchart's demos in my local anaconda Jupyter notebook (windows 10 machine), and while trying to display the chart, it throws a Highcharts.js script load error.

This is the Demo code:

```
from highcharts_core.chart import Chart
from highcharts_core.options import HighchartsOptions
from highcharts_core.options.plot_options import PlotOptions
from highcharts_core.options.axes.x_axis import XAxis
from highcharts_core.options.axes.y_axis import YAxis
from highcharts_core.options.axes.accessibility import AxisAccessibility
from highcharts_core.options.axes.title import AxisTitle
from highcharts_core.options.title import Title
from highcharts_core.options.subtitle import Subtitle
from highcharts_core.options.legend import Legend
from highcharts_core.options.plot_options.series import SeriesOptions
from highcharts_core.options.series.area import LineSeries
from highcharts_core.options.series.labels import SeriesLabel
from highcharts_core.options.responsive import Responsive, ResponsiveRules, Condition
from highcharts_core.constants import EnforcedNull


chart_options = HighchartsOptions(
    title = Title(text = 'U.S Solar Employment Growth by Job Category, 2010-2020',
                  align = 'left'),
    subtitle = Subtitle(text = 'Source: <a href="https://irecusa.org/programs/solar-jobs-census/" target="_blank">IREC</a>',
                        align = 'left'),
    y_axis = YAxis(title = AxisTitle(text = 'Number of Employees')),
    x_axis = XAxis(
        accessibility = AxisAccessibility(range_description = 'Range: 2010 to 2020')
    ),
    legend = Legend(layout = 'vertical',
                    align = 'right',
                    vertical_align = 'middle'),
    plot_options = PlotOptions(series = SeriesOptions(point_start = 2010,
                                                      label = SeriesLabel(connector_allowed = False)))
)

override_options = HighchartsOptions(legend = Legend(layout = 'horizontal',
                                                     align = 'center',
                                                     vertical_align = 'bottom'))
responsive_config = Responsive(
    rules = [
        ResponsiveRules(chart_options = override_options,
                        condition = Condition(max_width = 500))
    ]
)
chart_options.responsive = responsive_config

series1 = LineSeries(name = 'Installation & Developers',
                     data = [43934, 48656, 65165, 81827, 112143, 142383, 171533, 165174, 155157, 161454, 154610])
series2 = LineSeries(name = 'Manufacturing',
                     data = [24916, 37941, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 36885, 33726, 34243, 31050])
series3 = LineSeries(name = 'Sales & Distribution',
                     data = [11744, 30000, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 30912, 29243, 29213, 25663])
series4 = LineSeries(name = 'Operations & Maintenance',
                     data = [EnforcedNull, EnforcedNull, EnforcedNull, EnforcedNull, EnforcedNull, EnforcedNull, EnforcedNull, EnforcedNull, 11164, 11218, 10077])
series5 = LineSeries(name = 'Other',
                     data = [21908, 5548, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 17300, 13053, 11906, 10073])

chart_options.add_series(series1, series2, series3, series4, series5)

chart = Chart.from_options(chart_options)
chart.display()
```

Below is the error displayed,

```
Something went wrong with the Highcharts.js script. It should have been automatically loaded, but it did not load for over 5 seconds. Check your internet connection, and then if the problem persists please reach out for support. (You can also check your browser's console log for more details.)

Detailed Error Message:
Highcharts is not defined
```

Below are the versions I'm using,
python -  3.10.13

1. highcharts-core           1.3.7
2. ipython                   8.16.0
3. ipykernel                 6.25.2
4. jupyter_client            8.3.1
5. jupyter_client            8.3.1

I did try clearing out the cell output also restarting the kernel etc, but no joy!
Basically I tried the solutions specified in this stackoverflow question -
[Highcharts for Python doesn't render in Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76096200/highcharts-for-python-doesnt-render-in-jupyter)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Sorry you're having this trouble! This could be happening due to network connectivity issues between your environment and the Highcharts CDN (from which Highcharts (JS) modules are loaded), however I have one question to rule out certain potential issues:

Are you running this within a Jupyter Notebook in-browser, within a notebook opened in Jupyter Lab (in browser), or within a Jupyter Notebook opened in VSCode?

Depending on the answer to this question, I may have some alternative suggestions / additional questions, but this is a first important diagnostic.

Comment: Hi @ChrisModzelewski, the first option, I'm running within a jupyter notebook opened in the browser. Its a native jupyter notebook from anaconda.

Comment: Hi @VIJU - Thanks. In this case, my first suspicion is network connectivity. You can give HIghcharts for Python more time to download the Highcharts (JS) scripts by adjusting the ``.display()`` call. You can use more retries using ``.display(retries = 10)``, for example, which will give the chart up to 10 seconds to render. You can also adjust the ``.display(interval = 1000)`` to lengthen the interval between retries (default: 1 second). Another question to help with diagnostics is whether you have any browser extensions (e.g. ad blockers) installed/active? Those can also create this behavior.

Comment: Hi @ChrisModzelewski
I did try setting the retries and intervals already from your reply to my email, in this case it throws the same error in about 5 to 6 seconds of time. as of the extensions, I don't have any ad blocker extensions, I just have a webex extension and that's it.

Comment: Hi @VIJU - Thanks - can you try opening the same notebook within Jupyter Lab rather than in Jupyter Notebook (classic) itself? That may help rule out / rule-in one possible cause for the issue (specifically, a [RequireJS conflict](https://github.com/highcharts-for-python/highcharts-core/issues/66) for which a fix will be released this week. In the meantime, I'll try to re-create your environment with the versions listed in the original question to see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi @ChrisModzelewski , I just tried the same demo code in the jupyterlab again through the anaconda navigator, this works perfectly. I can use jupyterlab for time being, But, 
I would still prefer doing the experiments on the native Jupyter notebook itself, if this fix is coming this week, I can then swap back to using the notebook.
Thanks a ton for your help Chris!

Comment: Hi @VIJU - Great, thanks. Glad to hear that it is working fine in Jupyter Lab. That does suggest that the issue is caused by the [RequireJS conflict](https://github.com/highcharts-for-python/highcharts-core/issues/66) I'd mentioned, and that bugfix is currently awaiting release. I'm aiming for v.1.4.0 to be released tomorrow (Wednesday), though it might slide to Thursday as we put the finishing touches on the release. Either way, the bugfix that *should* fix this problem for you. I'll add a more complete StackOverflow answer here in the meantime, as well, based on our diagnostics.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion with OP in the comments, we determined:

1. This problem was occurring in Jupyter **Notebook** within the browser.
2. This problem was *not* occurring in Jupyter **Lab** within the browser.
3. We ruled out network connectivity issues.

Based on this, this seems to be an issue related to a [bug in Highcharts Core for Python](https://github.com/highcharts-for-python/highcharts-core/issues/66) in versions earlier than v.1.4.0 where Jupyter Notebook includes [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/) while Jupyter Lab does not.

This bug relates to a conflict that occurs in the browser between the JavaScript code which Highcharts for Python generates to render the visualization (specifically, to load required Highcharts JS scripts) in the notebook and [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/).

There is a fix for this bug in [PR#112](https://github.com/highcharts-for-python/highcharts-core/pull/112) which is already part of the release candidate for Highcharts Core for Python v.1.4.0, and which will be released on October 4th or 5th, 2023. Following release, this particular issue should be resolved after upgrading to the latest version.