# Highcharts in Jupyterlab Throws Highcharts.js script error while trying to display the charts on arearange

Tags: python, charts, highcharts, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to replicate one of the highchart's demos on area range with line charts (
/highcharts-core/area-charts/area-range-with-line.ipynb) in my local anaconda Jupyterlab opened in the browser (windows 10 machine), and while trying to display the chart, it throws a Highcharts.js script load error.

This is the Demo code:

```
from highcharts_core.chart import Chart
from highcharts_core.options import HighchartsOptions
from highcharts_core.options.series.area import AreaRangeSeries, LineSeries


ranges = [
    [13.7, 25.6],
    [13.3, 21.8],
    [11.2, 19.9],
    [7.9, 17.3],
    [4.9, 20.6],
    [5.1, 16.8],
    [9.3, 21.1]
]

averages = [
    [18.1],
    [17.1],
    [15.2],
    [12.7],
    [13.3],
    [10.6],
    [15.6],
    [16.1],
    [14.0],
    [15.3]
]


options = HighchartsOptions(
    title = { 'text': 'July temperatures in Nesbyen, 2022', 'align': 'left' },
    subtitle = {
        'text': 'Source: <a href="https://www.yr.no/nb/historikk/graf/1-113585/Norge/Viken/Nesbyen/Nesbyen?q=2022-07" target="_blank">YR</a>',
        'align': 'left'
    },
    x_axis = {
        'type': 'datetime',
        'accessibility': {
            'range_description': 'Range: Jul 1st 2022 to Jul 31st 2022.'
        }
    },
    y_axis = {
        'title': {
            'text': None
        }
    },
    tooltip = {
        'crosshairs': True,
        'shared': True,
        'value_suffix': '°C'
    },

    plot_options = {
        'series': {
            'point_start': '2022-06-01',
            'point_interval_unit': 'day'
        }
    })

range_series = AreaRangeSeries(name = 'Range',
                               data = ranges,
                               line_width = 0,
                               linked_to = ':previous',
                               fill_opacity = 0.3,
                               z_index = 0,
                               marker = {
                                   'enabled': False
                               })
averages_series = LineSeries(name = 'Temperature',
                             data = averages,
                             z_index = 1,
                             marker = {
                                 'fill_color': 'white',
                                 'line_width': 2
                             })
options.add_series(range_series, averages_series)

chart = Chart.from_options(options)
chart.display(retries = 10)
chart.display(interval = 1000)
```

Below is the error displayed,

```
Something went wrong with the Highcharts.js script. It should have been automatically loaded, but it did not load for over 10 seconds. Check your internet connection, and then if the problem persists please reach out for support. (You can also check your browser's console log for more details.)

Detailed Error Message:
Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=arearange - missingModuleFor: arearange
```

Below are the versions I'm using,
python -  3.10.13

1. highcharts-core           1.3.7
2. ipython                   8.16.0
3. ipykernel                 6.25.2
4. jupyter_client            8.3.1
5. jupyter_client            8.3.1

This is a follow up question from my below similar resolved stackoverflow question -

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hi @VIJU - Thanks. This looks to be an issue related to a [bug](https://github.com/highcharts-for-python/highcharts-core/issues/114) that I'm currently investigating. I'm hoping to have it fixed in the v.1.4 release which is being finalized right now - with luck, the fix will be released today (Monday, 9 October).

Comment: Hi @VIJU - I released v.1.4.0 which seems to have addressed the related bug. Can you try upgrading and trying again? Hopefully the issue is now resolved.

Comment: HI @ChrisModzelewski , Just upgraded to V.1.4.0 in the same environment. I can confirm that the arearange chart is working in the jupyterlab now.
I thought this version is going to clear the jupyter issue that I raised earlier - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77201981/highcharts-in-jupyter-notebook-throws-highcharts-js-script-error-while-trying-to
So I tired the same in jupyter. but that still doesn't work in there, still throws js script error for both lineseries and area range series.
Thanks for your support!

Comment: Hi @VIJU - Thanks, it likely should have addressed the issue. Can you share with me (possibly via email to support@highcharts.com) the output of your browser's console and a screengrab of the "sources" tab visible when viewing Developer Tools in your browser? That may help diagnose if there is something else going on.